# Angular router not navigating to the route

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-fullstack

I am working on an Angular app where I am using the following structure:

- app

  - layouts

    - admin-layout
  - pages

    - dashboard
    - icons
    - table
    - user
  - shared
  - sidebar

I am trying to write auth-guard.service.ts and auth.service.ts in admin-layout as I have defined my routing there for the pages that I want to access on DOM.

However, when I try to login in dashboard page it doesn't navigate to the route that I have written in the code. But, when I click on the route on the sidebar it only prints the variable as true which is what the auth-guard here does. It doesn't navigate to that route. Here is my code:

> admin-layout.routing.ts

```
export const AdminLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'dashboard',      component: DashboardComponent },
{ path: 'user',           component: UserComponent },
{ path: 'table',  canActivate: [AuthGuard],        component: TableComponent }, 
{ path: 'icons',          component: IconsComponent }
];
```

> auth-guard.service.ts

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router){}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | 
Promise<boolean> | boolean
{

return this.authService.isAuthenticated().then(
  (authenticated: boolean) => {
    if(authenticated){
      console.log('accessed this if part'); 
      this.router.navigate(["/table"]); // isn't navigating to this 
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("Accessed else part");
      return false;
    }
  }
)

}
```

> auth.service.ts

```
export class AuthService
{
 loggedIn:boolean;
 isAuthenticated()
{
 const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(this.loggedIn);
  }, 100);
}
);
return promise;
}

check_Authentication(logIn : boolean)
{
if(logIn == true)
{
  this.loggedIn = true;
  }
 }
}
```

> dashboard.component.ts

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private authService: AuthService){}
private onAuthorization(form: NgForm)
{
  this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/auth', form.value, {responseType: "text"})
  .subscribe(responseData =>{
    console.log(responseData);
    if(responseData == "Successfully Authorized")
    {
      this.auth_check = true;
      this.authService.check_Authentication(this.auth_check);
    }
    else
    {
      this.auth_failed = true;
    }

  }
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?
Edit: When I try to access the route by clicking on the table on my sidebar then an infinite loop starts printing the same thing.

Comment: could you share the github link to your project sourcecode ?

Comment: @divine, I am writing the code by myself. I will upload it on Github once it completes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use child components as follows

```
{
   path: 'parent', component: ParentComponent, children:
    [
     { path: 'child', component: ChildComponent }
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return true:

```
if(authenticated){
  console.log('accessed this if part'); 
  this.router.navigate(["/table"]); // isn't navigating to this 
  return true; <----- here
}
```

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue. The router doesn't navigate to table after I log in in my dashboard. However, when I click on the table route which I am displaying in my sidebar then an infinite loop starts repeating the same thing on my angular console, it still doesn't open the table section.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. For anyone going to see this question for help, as I am new to Angular and don't know much stuff so I decided to simplify my code. I resolved it by writing my code this way:

> admin-layout.routing.ts

```
export const AdminLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'dashboard',      component: DashboardComponent },
{ path: 'user',           component: UserComponent },
{ path: 'table',  canActivate: [AuthGuard],        component: TableComponent },
{ path: 'icons',          component: IconsComponent }
];
```

> auth-guard.service.ts

```
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } 
from "@angular/router";

constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router){}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean
{
  if(this.authService.isAuthenticated())
  {
    this.router.navigate['/table']; //this is although not working, I'll resolve it
    return true;
  }
return false;
}
```

> auth.service.ts

```
export class AuthService
{
 loggedIn:boolean;

 check_Authentication(logIn : boolean)
{
 if(logIn == true)
 {
  this.loggedIn = true;
 }
 else
 {
  this.loggedIn = false;
 }
}

isAuthenticated()
{
 if(this.loggedIn == true)
 {
  return true;
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
 }
}
}
```

> dashboard.component.ts

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private authService: 
AuthService){}

private onAuthorization(form: NgForm)
{
  this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/auth', form.value, {responseType: "text"})
  .subscribe(responseData =>{
    console.log(responseData);
    if(responseData == "Successfully Authorized")
    {
      this.auth_check = true;
      this.authService.check_Authentication(this.auth_check);
    }
    else
    {
      this.auth_failed = true;
    }

  }
  ,error => {
    this.connectionToServer = false;
  });
  this.connectionToServer = true;
}
```